# Are these graphs isomorphic? (can't find bijection)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Are these graphs isomorphic? They have same number of vertices, same degrees, and each one connects to a graph of the same degree, but I can't find a bijection.

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyMLz.png

Comment: Make sure to preview your questions before you post them. Also, if possible, embed the two images directly in your question. Furthermore, it's advisable to explain what you've already tried, and to be clear about _why_ you're having difficulty answering the question for yourself.

Comment: I have tried to count the vertexes,check the vertexe's degree , check if the vertexes connect to vertexes of different degree , although i cant find a bijection.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** Please consider updating your post by fixing typos, adding context, and including what you have tried so far. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not isomorphic. If you count carefully, you'll find that there are $9$ cycles of length $5$ on the graph on the right, but only $5$ on the left. Alternatively, as @MishaLavrov has pointed out in the comments, the graph on the left has a $4$-cycle but not the graph on the right.

Comment: It may be easier to check that the graph on the right has no cycles of length $4$.